# PHP Array Undefined Index error

Tags: php

My script was working perfectly fine for ages then this error cropped up saying I have an undefined index that won't allow me to add products to my shopping cart.

> PHP: Notice 'undefined index: product_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Autoparts Warehouse2\grilles.php on line 243

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_products"])>0) { 
    echo ' ';
    echo ' Your Shopping Cart '; 
    echo ' '; 
    echo ''; 
    echo ''; 
    $total =0; 
    $b = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm) 
        print_r($cart_itm); {
        $product_name  = $cart_itm["product_name"];
        $product_qty   = $cart_itm["product_qty"]; 
        $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
        $product_code  = $cart_itm["product_code"];
        $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
```

I have tried using `$_POST` and `$_GET` also but to neither have worked any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: I have tried everything on this other question already and nothing has worked for me, their question looks different to mine?

Comment: Sorry about that are you able to read the code now?

Comment: Do `print_r($cart_itm)` in the foreach, what do you have?

Comment: Hi there, it returns that as an unexpected string?

Comment: Can you update the code to show where you put it?

Comment: not sure if I have entered it correctly into the code

Comment: No. You didn't. You should add the print_r inside of the foreach to debug output the contents of the variable you've assigned (within curly braces).

Comment: The `foreach` should be as it was, then the next line should be `print_r($cart_itm);`. You could even `exit();` after that because we only need 1 iteration.

Comment: so the code should look like the edited one now?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `session_start()` at the top of your code?

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) ) {
    if( count($_SESSION["cart_products"]) > 0 ){
        echo ' '; 
        echo ' Your Shopping Cart '; 
        echo ' '; 
        echo ''; 
        echo ''; 
        $total =0; 
        $b = 0; 
        foreach ( $_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm ) { 
            $product_name   = $cart_itm["product_name"]; 
            $product_qty    = $cart_itm["product_qty"]; 
            $product_price  = $cart_itm["product_price"]; 
            $product_code   = $cart_itm["product_code"]; 
            $product_color  = $cart_itm["product_color"];
        }
    }
}
```

You can try like this. Because if `$_SESSION["cart_products"]` not set then `count($_SESSION["cart_products"])` is also not set. Thanks.

Comment: have edited my code accordingly but unfortunately still getting the same error returned that there is an undefined index: product_name

Comment: `$product_name   = isset( $cart_itm["product_name"] ) ? $cart_itm["product_name"] : '';` try this, I think you didn't set `$cart_itm["product_name"]`. Thanks.